# How can you go about troubleshooting errors in SQL Server 2012 Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I'm in the process of creating a report in the latest version of SQL Server 2012 Report Builder but there are errors that I can't localize or troubleshoot because I'm not sure this functionality exists.  I have the T-SQL behind this code rock solid but my question isn't about the coding, it's how can one go about troubleshooting errors in report samples through this application when all that shows up is '#ERROR' (instead of more detailed error text)?

Comment: This is a pretty terrible solution, but you download the free version of BIDS to troubleshoot - just open the file and preview and it will show these runtime errors. If you don't have the local file you can download the RDL from the server. I typically see these errors with data type mismatches - try casting literals CDec() or similar to resolve. It's a pretty big oversight in Report Builder not to show these. The Report Server log files might have some info, but they generally don't log too much info for these sorts of things - worth a try, though.

Comment: @IanPreston You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @IanPreston Agreed, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Would it be easier to just to do these reports through Visual Studio?  Not sure what a better solution would be.  This reminds me of the early versions of Front Page and trying to get it to talk to early versions of IIS with the lack of information provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSRS report development in Visual Studio (or BIDS if you've only installed SQL Server) does give more options for debugging these sort of errors than Report Builder. In VS:

[image]

You can see there is a clear error message here.

As you've found, Report Builder doesn't have any sort of similar functionality - seems a pretty big oversight for a nominal development tool.

Running this report through a Report Server and checking any logged errors doesn't help, either; all that's logged is the following:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
> The specified operation is not valid. ;

So that's hardly going to help.

If you do have the option to use VS, do it. Report Builder has pretty much all of the same functionality, but it's situations like this when it falls over.

For what it's worth, when I've had these errors these are often due to datatype conversions (as above) - hopefully the problem expression isn't too complicated to investigate.